# Using ContourPlot of a Potential surface Image

Tags: plotting

I did this image, using Contour plot:
[image: Potentia Image]

and the code is:

```
Module[{a = 246./100, 
  V = 5./10},     
 dataGraf = 
  ContourPlot[ -V *(2 Cos[(2 \[Pi] x)/a] Cos[(2 \[Pi] y)/(
        a Sqrt[3])] + Cos[(4 \[Pi] y)/(a Sqrt[3])]), {x, 0, 10.}, {y, 
    0, 10.}, Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> Tiny, Contours -> 300, 
   ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]]
```

But, when I tried repeat the same code, the image was not the same, even the numbers in scale axis  were exaggerated:

[image: Second Image]

I am using Open Suse 13.1, 8 gig ram, is the same pc and same configuration.

SECOND QUESTION:  Why in both images is there a white space between the axis and the image? (and why Have the numbers gone bigger?) I need see the origin axis inside or besides the image and not far from it.

Observation: When doing such images, the system goes very slow, with lag, I change to use separates kernels , but even that did not fix the slowing front end running.

EDIT 1: I forgot put the second part of the code:

```
SetDirectory["............../,,,,,,,"];
Export["GrafPotent.bmp", dataGraf, "BMP", 
  ImageResolution -> 600];
SystemOpen["GrafPotent.bmp"]

Quit[];
```

EDIT2: LINKS TO THE IMAGES: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37906119/PotencialGraf.jpg

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37906119/GrafPotentTomlinsonPRB_tiny.bmp

EDIT 3: i TRIED SOME MODIFICATIONS:

including:

```
ImageSize -> 400, Contours -> 110, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, Axes \
-> True, PlotLegends -> Automatic
```

It worked better, no more lags, and slowing, What could it be?
[Image_3](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37906119/GrafPotentTomlinsonPRB_tiny4.bmp)

EDIT 4:

Final Image from the code:

```
a = 246./100; V = .5/10;
dataGraf = 
 ContourPlot[ -V *(2 Cos[(2 \[Pi] x)/a] Cos[(2 \[Pi] y)/(a Sqrt[3])] +
      Cos[(4 \[Pi] y)/(a Sqrt[3])]), {x, 0, 10.}, {y, 0, 10.}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, ImageSize -> 200, Contours -> 110, 
  Axes -> True, PlotRangePadding -> None, FormatType -> StandardForm, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x [\[Angstrom]]", "y [\[Angstrom]]"},
   PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 150, 
    LegendFunction -> "Frame", LegendMargins -> 5, 
    LegendLabel -> "Potential value\n\t[e.v]"],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"(*,ColorFunction\[Rule](ColorData[
  "TemperatureMap"][Rescale[#,{0,10}]]&)*)]
SetDirectory["/home/marcelo/Documentos/Tomlinson/imagens/"];
Export["GrafPotentTomlinsonPRB_Cor3.jpeg", dataGraf, "JPEG", 
 ImageResolution -> 600, ImageMargins -> 10]
```

[image: Potential surface in color imae]

I tried to highlight the minima values in small blue colors circles.

Comment: Posting the image file/s would make assessing this much easier.

Comment: Seems to be an artifact from using `imageSize->Tiny`  

You can remove the gap by using PlotRangePadding->0.

Comment: SO, tiny could be the problem for slowing down? Bug?

Comment: Could you reduce the topic to one issue with minimal example of code? It's a little messy at the moment.